# Post increment and addition

Tags: javascript, addition

I don't understand why in this example addition doesn't work:

```
<button id="button">Click</button>
<p id="counter"></p>

function handler(){
    var button = document.getElementById('button'),
    count = document.getElementById('counter'); // 
    count.textContent = 0;


    button.onclick = function(){
    count.textContent++; //Why this works

    //but this does not
    //count.textContent + 1;  

    console.log(typeof count.textContent); // Why is a string?
    }

}

window.onload = handler;
```

And why `(typeof count.textContent)` is  a `string`?

Comment: When you say `count.textContent + 1` doesn't work, what exactly do you mean? Does it concatenate? That would make sense because `+` is defined for strings as the concatenation operator so "1" + 1 == "11". But `++` isn't. So javascript will first convert the string to a number, increment it and then convert it back to a string.

Comment: By the way, when **setting** the `textContent` property, it will take whatever value you're trying to set it with and convert it to a string. So when you do `count.textContent = 0;`, it's actually using `"0"`. And if you're asking **why** it's a string, look at the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#Node3-textContent

Answer (score 2):

This will only work, If written like this:

```
   count.textContent = parseInt(count.textContent) + 1;
```

count.textContent++ store the value in count.textContent after incrementing.

But In case of count.textContent + 1, it is required to store the incremented value in some variable;

Comment: It should be parse to int value before increament.

Answer (score 2):

```
count.textContent++; //Why this works
```

The above line is equivalent to `count.textContent = count.textContent +1;`
It also parses the variable as a numeric one.

Whereas the below one is only a statement on a String:

```
//count.textContent + 1;
```

So you need to use the following:

```
count.textContent = parseInt(count.textContent) + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

`textContent` as the name suggests is a string. When you do this (and actually assign the value to something):

```
count.textContent = count.textContent + 1;
```

Javascript will interpret this as a `string` + a `number` and, since `+` is the concatenation operator for strings, it will convert the number to a string and then stick them together. So you get:

```
"0" + "1" = "01"
```

When you do this:

```
count.textContent++;
```

The `++` operator isn't defined for strings, but it is for numbers. So javascript will (attempt to) convert your string to a number, increment it and then convert it back to a string and store it back in `count.textContent`

The equivalent statement would be something like:

```
count.textContent = parseInt(count.textContent,10) + 1;
```

Comment: This is mostly cottect. Javascript will coerce the value into a number, but only if it's 'number-like'. `x='1'; x++` will return `2`, while `x='1foo'; x++` will throw an error.

Comment: @ckersch: Yes - I assumed that when without saying, but it is a good clarification.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of the question, `count.textContent + 1` is a statement returning 1 plus the current value. It does not modify the content.

`count.textContent++` modifies the content and returns the unmodified number.

`count.textContent = count.textContent + 1` would modify the content and return the modified number which is equivalent to `++count.textContent`.

For the second part of the question, an element's `textContent` is always a string. By using an addition (`+`) operator, you are casting string `"0"` to number `0` and then modifying the resulting number.

Answer (score 0):

They are different operators.

`++X` is the increment operator. It functions by adding one to `X`, and then returning the current value of `X`. You can read it as 'Add one to `X`, then return `X`.

The increment operator can also come after something. `X++` will return the current value of `X`, and then increment it.

`+` is the addition operator. It does not modify the values of the things it is used on. `X + Y` could be read as 'return the value of `X` + `Y`. It does not modify either argument. It is also commutative, so `X+Y === Y+X' when`X`and`Y` are both numbers.

They also have different behavior when used on strings. `+` will concatenate strings, so `'foo' + 'bar' === 'foobar'`. `++` is not defined for strings, so it will throw an error, or it will coerce the value it's given into a number.

`element.textContent` is a property that returns as a string. If you use this:

```
element.textContent++;
```

The value will be coerced into a number, increased by one, and the value after that will be returned. (Right now, you aren't doing anything with the return value)

If you use this:

```
element.textContent + 1;
```

The statement will return a string: `'01'`.

Again, you aren't setting anything to this, and `+` doesn't change the arguments. Javascript, by default, will try to coerce to the left argument (`X` in `X + Y`), so `1 + '0' === 1` and `'1' + 0 === '10'`.